# Like button popup not showing Title, Description and Image

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I am having trouble displaying the Title, Description and Image fields in the popup window when a user clicks on the Like button. The fields are blank. This only happens on first page load. When I refresh the page, the Like button works as expected. I have checked the og: meta tags in the pages view source on initial page load and they contain the correct content. I also ran the Ul in the Facebook debugger and the same result happens.

Any ideas why the user would have to refresh the page to get this to occur?